# Visual Studio 2015 Intellisense showing question marks

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, intellisense

In VS2015 if I view the debug info while on a breakpoint, when I scroll down, the intellisense shows part of the debug info and then the list shows only question marks.

[image]

I have run VS in safe mode as well as reset all the setting to default and neither option has helped.

Setting "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" in Tools - Options - Debugging - General returns normal functionality without the question marks.

This problem has only recently started so is due to some update. How can I fix this without using Managed Compatibility mode?